# NextJs best practise/where to to set the page to fullscreen

Tags: next.js

Building a NextJS application, the `__next div`  will only be as high as the elements it contains.
If I want to add a `button` to the bottom of a page, the page needs to be "fullscreen", e.g. `height: 100vh`

So my question is: Where do I apply that fullscreen style? Inside the `_app.js`, `_document.js` or somewhere else?

I am also using Material UI, in case that changes anything

Comment: Omg I thought it was just me going crazy! I created a _global_scss file and set the body in that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would personally add it to a global CSS file that you then import in your `_app.js` as explained here: https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/built-in-css-support

Additionally, I would target it on the `body` of the document, in fact this question has nothing to do with Next.js, but more of a generic problem.

CSS I'd suggest you to try, note that 100vh does not work as expected on iOS, explained here: https://www.bram.us/2020/05/06/100vh-in-safari-on-ios/

```
body  {
  min-height: 100vh;
  min-height: -webkit-fill-available;
}
```